# Parallelizing python3 program with huge complex objects

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, parallel-processing, gil, dill

### Intro

I have a quite complex python program (say more than 5.000 rows) written with **Python 3.6**. This program parses a huge dataset of more than 5.000 files, processes them creating an internal representation of the dataset and then creates statistics. Since I have to test the model, I need to save the dataset representation and at now I'm doing it by using serialization through `dill` (in the representation there are objects that `pickle` does not support). The serialization of the whole dataset, not compressed, takes about 1GB.

### The problem

Now, I would like to speed up computation by parallelization. The perfect way would be a multithreading approach but GIL forbid that. `multiprocessing` module (and `multiprocess`  - which is `dill` compatible - too) uses serialization to share complex objects between processes so that, in the best case I managed to invent, parallelization is ininfluent for me on time performance because of the huge size of the dataset.

### The question

*What is the best way to manage this situation?*

I know about `posh`, but it seems to be only `x86` compatible, `ray` but it uses serialization too, `gilectomy` (a version of python without gil) but I'm not able to make it parallelize threads and `Jython` which has no GIL but is not compatible with python 3.x.

I am open to any alternative, any language, however complex it may be, but I can't rewrite the code from scratch.

Comment: Do you need to have the entire dataset available to all processors? Is it something that could be put into a shared memory `Array` (or some other form of shared memory object from `multiprocess`)?

Comment: To my understanding, multiprocess (and multiprocessing since their interfaces are compliant)  is able to manage only ctypes in shared memory. Dataset representation is a `List[Tuple(String, List[StreamReduction])]`, where `StreamReduction` is a python object created by me and composed by other objects created by me and the latter are in turn composed by `music21` objects, which are even more complex. So it is very hard to translate my `StreamReduction` to C types, even if it is, theoretically, possible. Yes, I need to compare each `StreamReduction` to all the dataset, which is a `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Yeah, anything that is a C type object should work with a `Manager`... but if you have your own class... hmm, I'm not sure then.  So, ouch, if you need to compare to the whole dataset that's a bad situation.  Totally off the top of my head... what about using parallel processing with `nogil` in `cython`, or something similar?  It would involve a bit of a serious rewrite, but maybe you'd have to in this case.

Comment: Yes, `nogil` and `cython` could be a chance but I would need a wrapper to convert Python objects to C structs because in `no gil` blocks only C data ca be touched

Comment: I found that dill really slows down everything. Maybe solving that issue could help...

Comment: I think that no matter what, pickling is going to be slower than using shared memory.  There are a few things in `dill` that enable smaller pickles -- for example `dill.settings['byref'] = True` which enables `dill` to pickle classes and the like by reference -- however, another potential approach would be to add a `reduce` or `reduce_ex` method to your class that directs `dill` to dump only the state you need to make the comparison.

Comment: yes, I just discovered that the main library I am using has a proper way to serialize objects. I think that `__reduce__` could help. But the main problem here is shared memory. I thik that there is no straight solution. I was a Python entusiast but this really disappoint me

Comment: Well if you think you have a satisfactory answer, then you should answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution I found is change `dill` to a custom pickling module based on standard `pickle`. See here: [Python 3.6 pickling custom procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48772727/python-3-6-pickling-custom-procedure/)