# Python 3.6 pickling custom procedure

Tags: python, pickle

I have some objects of class `A` which has its own method to be pickled, call it `custom_module.customPickle(A)` which takes an instance of `A` and returns a serialization string.
I also have list of objects each of class `B` that contains `A`.

I need to pickle the list, but pickling `A` gives some error difficult to solve. However, `A` has its own method to be pickled.

I can implement the `__reduce__()` method in class `B` so that it calls `custom_module.customPickle(A)`. But how can I do this so that `pickle` is able to serialize `B` efficiently?

---

Object `A` is a `music21.stream` and object `B` is a custom object. The custom serialization function is [`music21.converter.freezeStr(streamObj, fmt=None)`](http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/moduleReference/moduleConverter.html#music21.converter.freezeStr) and the unpickle function should be [`music21.converter.thawStr(strData)`](http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/moduleReference/moduleConverter.html#music21.converter.thawStr)

Comment: Do read https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances, especially the dispatch tables section.

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`copyreg` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copyreg.html) to register custom functions for pickling and unpickling; the function you register acts like a [`__reduce__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__) on the class.

If you return a tuple of `(unpickle_function, state)`, then the registered `unpickle_function` callable will be called to unpickle it again, with state as the argument, so you can use your `music21.converter.thawStr()` function there:

```
import copyreg
import music21.converter
import music21.stream


def pickle_music21_stream(stream_obj):
    return music21.converter.thawStr, (music21.converter.freezeStr(stream_obj),)

copyreg.pickle(music21.stream.Stream, pickle_music21_stream)
```

(the `constructor` argument to `copyreg` is ignored in recent Python versions)

This registers a *global* handler for those objects. You can also use a dispatch table per pickler, see [*Dispatch Tables on how you'd register one.

Now, when pickling, when encountering any instances of `Stream` the `handle_stream()` function is used to produce a serialisation, and the `thawStr()` function will be used to unpickle that data again.

*However*, the `music21.converter` functions use pickle themselves. They effectively pack and clean up the stream, and then pickle the resulting `Stream` instance. This will then call the custom handler, and you have an infinite loop.

The work-around is to use a custom [dispatch table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#dispatch-tables) to handle pickling and unpickling. Avoid using `copyreg` in this case, as it sets a global hook that'll be called recursively each time a `Stream` object is being pickled.

Your own pickle infrastructure needs to use a custom pickler:

```
import copyreg
import io
import pickle
import music21.converter
import music21.stream


def pickle_music21_stream(stream_obj):
    return music21.converter.thawStr, (music21.converter.freezeStr(stream_obj),)


def dumps(obj):
    f = io.BytesIO()
    p = pickle.Pickler(f)
    p.dispatch_table = copyreg.dispatch_table.copy()
    p.dispatch_table[music21.stream.Stream] = pickle_music21_stream
    p.dump(obj)
    return f.getvalue()


def loads(data):
    return pickle.loads(data)  # hook is registered in the pickle data
```

Here the custom function is only called when a `Stream` instance is found in your own data structure. The `music21` routines use the global `pickle.dumps()` and `pickle.loads()` functions and won't use the same hook.

Comment: It seems to work, but gives an error with a very very long stack trace: 'RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object'

Comment: Could you put that up in a pastie or gist somewhere? Not sure what would be recursing here. Perhaps the `music.stream` serialisation code uses pickle itself?

Comment: @fortea: just found the documentation; the default and only available format is to use pickle. `freezeStr()` is just a wrapper around the `pickle` module here and you shouldn’t need to use the custom functions in my answer *at all*.

Comment: I misunderstood the documentation, then. Maybe this issue is more music21 related...

Comment: @fortea: and finally, a tested version (from an empty `Stream()` instance).

Comment: This works! It was 5 days that I tried to do this! I love you! Do you also know how I can use this custom pickler with `multiprocessing` module?

Comment: @fortea: use `import multiprocessing` then `multiprocessing.reducer.register(music21.stream.Stream, pickle_music21_stream)` to register the handler for the custom pickler that multiprocessing uses (it'll do the same thing as the code in my answer, use the function for a specific pickler, leaving the `music21` module pickle use untouched and working).

Comment: thanks, it works! I updated the answer to include this :)

Comment: @fortea: that's rather a separate issue, perhaps worthy of a separate question, but doesn't need to be added to this answer.